# Como puedo eliminar elementos repetidos de un array multidimensional en javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un ecommerce solo con javascript y mediante un boton debo agregar productos a un carrito. Todo funciona bien pero el problema es que al apretar dos veces un mismo boton de agregar al carrito ,me duplica el mismo. La idea seria que no existan elementos duplicados pero no se como hacerlo. El boton de agregar al carrito hace un push(carrito.push) para agregar los productos a un array llamado carrito y estos mismos se guardan como un array multidimensional y con un id que los identifica. Habrá alguna manera de eliminar los duplicados teniendo en cuenta el id de cada producto. Auqui les muestro como se ve en consola y como podrán ver hay productos duplicados. Desde ya muchas gracias por leer esto.

```
aCarrito= 
0:{carritoId: "1", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg", carritoNombre: "Oyster Perpetual 41", carritoCategoria: "Hombre", carritoPrecio: "6400"}
1: {carritoId: "1", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg", carritoNombre: "Oyster Perpetual 41", carritoCategoria: "Hombre", carritoPrecio: "6400"}
2: {carritoId: "2", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg", carritoNombre: "Lady Datejust", carritoCategoria: "Mujer", carritoPrecio: "41250"}
3: {carritoId: "2", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg", carritoNombre: "Lady Datejust", carritoCategoria: "Mujer", carritoPrecio: "41250"}
length: 4 

function AgregarCarrito(){
    let carritoId=this.dataset.id;
    let carritoImg= this.dataset.src;
    let carritoNombre= this.dataset.nombre;
    let carritoCategoria=this.dataset.categoria;
    let carritoPrecio= this.dataset.precio;
    aCarrito.push ({carritoId,carritoImg,carritoNombre,carritoCategoria,})    
     cl(aCarrito);
//Agregar al carrito 
 //Sintaxis literal
/*
            <ul class="padding">
            <li class="producto_carrito">
                <picture>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </picture>
                <div class="detalles_producto">
                    <h2>Nombre Producto</h2>
                    <p>Categoría</p>
                    <p>$300</p>
                </div>
               
            </li>

        </ul>
*/    
       let carritoUl=document.querySelector('#carrito ul');
       let liCarrito=document.createElement('li');
       liCarrito.classList.add('producto_carrito');
       carritoUl.appendChild(liCarrito);
       
       let pictureCarrito=document.createElement('picture');
       liCarrito.appendChild(pictureCarrito);
       
       let imgCarrito=document.createElement('img');
       pictureCarrito.appendChild(imgCarrito);
       imgCarrito.src=this.dataset.src;
     
       let detallesCarrito=document.createElement('div');
       detallesCarrito.classList.add('detalles_producto');
       liCarrito.appendChild(detallesCarrito);
       
       let nombreCarrito=document.createElement('h2');
       detallesCarrito.appendChild(nombreCarrito);
       nombreCarrito.innerHTML=this.dataset.nombre;
     
       let categoriaCarrito=document.createElement('p');
       detallesCarrito.appendChild(categoriaCarrito);
       categoriaCarrito.innerHTML=this.dataset.categoria;
      
       let precioCarrito=document.createElement('p');
       detallesCarrito.appendChild(precioCarrito);   
       precioCarrito.innerHTML=`$${this.dataset.precio}`; 
     
      let eliminar=document.createElement('span');
      liCarrito.appendChild(eliminar);
      eliminar.innerHTML='x';
      eliminar.classList.add('eliminar')
      eliminar.onclick=function(){
          aCarrito.pop();
          aPrecios.pop()
          CantidadDeProductos();
          Total();
          liCarrito.remove();
          liCheckout.remove()
          if(aCarrito.length==0){
              location.reload();
          }
          cl(aCarrito);
      }

//Resumen del carrito en checkout
 //Sintaxis literal
/*
    <li class="producto_carrito padding">
                <picture>
                    <img src="" alt="">
                </picture>
                <div class="detalles_producto">
                    <h2>Nombre Producto</h2>
                    <p>Categoría</p>
                    <p>$0</p>
                </div>
                <p>0 productos</p>
            </li>
*/

let ulCheckout=document.querySelector('#checkout_pagina ul');

let liCheckout=document.createElement('li');
liCheckout.classList.add('producto_carrito','padding');
ulCheckout.appendChild(liCheckout);

let pictureChekcout=document.createElement('picture');
liCheckout.appendChild(pictureChekcout);

let imgChekcout=document.createElement('img');
pictureChekcout.appendChild(imgChekcout);
imgChekcout.src=this.dataset.src;

let divChekcout=document.createElement('div');
liCheckout.appendChild(divChekcout);

let nombreChekcout=document.createElement('h2');
divChekcout.appendChild(nombreChekcout);
nombreChekcout.innerHTML=this.dataset.nombre;

let categoriaChekcout=document.createElement('p');
divChekcout.appendChild(categoriaChekcout);
categoriaChekcout.innerHTML=this.dataset.categoria;

let precioChekcout=document.createElement('p');
divChekcout.appendChild(precioChekcout);
precioChekcout.innerHTML=`$${this.dataset.precio}`;

let cantidadChekcout=document.createElement('cantidad');
liCheckout.appendChild(cantidadChekcout);
cantidadChekcout.innerHTML='0 X';


//Acumular y contar precios
   aPrecios.push(parseInt(this.dataset.precio));
    Total();
//Cantidad de productos agregados
    CantidadDeProductos(); 

//Validación si hay productos en el carrito
if (aCarrito.length >= 1){
    let noProductos=document.querySelector('#carrito_pagina .no_productos');
    noProductos.remove();

    let btnCarrito=document.querySelector('#carrito_pagina .cont_btn a');
    btnCarrito.href='#checkout_pagina';
    btnCarrito.style.opacity='1'
}  
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué dejar que se dupliquen los productos? Sería mejor que verifiques que no existen en el carrito antes de agregarlos o, mejor aún, incrementar la cantidad si un producto ya existe; lamentablemente, parece que no tienes considerado que se puedan pedir 2 o más de un mismo producto.

Comment: @Triby y como podría hacer para verificarlos?

Comment: @Michael, edita la pregunta para poner el código que usas para agregar productos al carrito.

Comment: @Triby ya edite el código. Los data set son del boton de agregar al carrito de cada producto

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Usar [`new Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set)

Esta característica  es soportada desde ES6, es simple

```js
const myArray = [0,"a",0,1,"a",1];
const uniqueElements = [...new Set(myArray)];
console.log(uniqueElements);
```

> Los tres puntos **NO son un error tipográfico**

Nos devuelve los elementos únicos de un array, en este caso

```
[
  0,
  "a",
  1
]
```

---

#### 2. Usar [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)

Puedes usar [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), creando un array diferente y comprobando si existe un elemento igual en el array

```js
const array_unique = (arr) => {
  const unique = [];
  arr.forEach(el => {
    unique.filter(a => a === el).length === 0 ? unique.push(el) : undefined;
  });
  return unique;
};

console.log(array_unique([0,"a",0,1,"a",1,"b","a","c","a","d",0,1]));
```

Usamos un [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) para evaluar una condición, tiene la siguiente sintaxis

```
condition ? value true : value false
```

Ponemos `undefined` en *value false*, para no hacer ninguna operación si no se cumple la condición, si se cumple, haremos un `push` al array

Usaremos [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para saber si es que existe un elemento existente e igual al actual, de no existir se hace el `push()`

---

#### 3. Usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Podemos iterar cada elemento del array con [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), obteniendo el índice, luego usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para comprobar si hay un elemento existente e igual al actual en el array, de haberlo usar [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) para eliminar el índice actual dentro del array

```js
const array_unique = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((el,i) => {
    if (arr.filter(a => a === el).length !== 0) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  return arr;
};

console.log(array_unique([{carritoId: "1", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg", carritoNombre: "Oyster Perpetual 41", carritoCategoria: "Hombre", carritoPrecio: "6400"}, {carritoId: "1", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg", carritoNombre: "Oyster Perpetual 41", carritoCategoria: "Hombre", carritoPrecio: "6400"}, {carritoId: "2", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg", carritoNombre: "Lady Datejust", carritoCategoria: "Mujer", carritoPrecio: "41250"}, {carritoId: "2", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/lady_datejust.jpg", carritoNombre: "Lady Datejust", carritoCategoria: "Mujer", carritoPrecio: "41250"}]));
```

Comment: Es importante resaltar que la mejor opción es la del Set ya que es la más rápida de todas, la complejidad algorítimca de las demás opciones es mucho más alta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, el formato que mencionas en la pregunta:

```
[
  {carritoId: "1", carritoImg: "./img/rolex/oyster_perpetual_41.jpg", carritoNombre: "Oyster Perpetual 41", carritoCategoria: "Hombre", carritoPrecio: "6400"}
]
```

No coincide con lo que armas dentro de la función, que quedaría:

```
[
    {"1", "imagen del producto", "Nombre", "Categoría"}
]
```

Quiero suponer que fue para simplificar la pregunta y sí usas el primer formato con `nombreDePropiedad: "Valor"`. Y vamos a aprovechar para agregar cantidad (opcionalmente).

Hay que obtener ID del producto y buscar si existe en el carrito antes de agregarlo. El método [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/findIndex) es el que sirve para buscar y obtener la posición del duplicado:

```
function AgregarCarrito(){
    let carritoId=this.dataset.id;
    let carritoCantidad = 1;
    let carritoImg= this.dataset.src;
    let carritoNombre= this.dataset.nombre;
    let carritoCategoria=this.dataset.categoria;
    let carritoPrecio= this.dataset.precio;

    // Buscar si ya existe o no
    let existe = aCarrito.findIndex(item => item.id == carritoId);
    // Si hubo coincidencia, entonces existe debe ser mayor o igual que cero
    if(existe >= 0) {
        // Ya existe el producto en el carrito

        /* ***** Elimina desde aquí para no incrementar cantidad ***** */
        // Si te gusta la idea de incrementar cantidad
        // Sumar a cantidad encontrada
        aCarrito[existe].carritoCantidad ++;
        /*
          * Aquí debes modificar el HTML correspondiente para actualizar la cantidad
          * También debes actualizar totales
        */
        /* ***** Elimina hasta aquí para no incrementar cantidad ***** */
        return;
    }
    // No existe en el carrito, hay que insertar
    aCarrito.push({
        carritoId: carritoId,
        carritoCantidad: carritoCantidad,
        carritoImg: carritoImg,
        carritoNombre: carritoNombre,
        carritoCategoria: carritoCategoria,
        carritoPrecio: carritoPrecio
    });
    /* ***** Aquí continúa tu función para crear el HTML necesario ***** */
}
```

Una gran mejora que puedes aplicar es asignar ID a cada contenedor de carrito, para poder manipular más fácilmente:

```
   let carritoUl=document.querySelector('#carrito ul');
   let liCarrito=document.createElement('li');
   liCarrito.classList.add('producto_carrito');
   // Asignar ID
   liCarrito.id = 'producto-' + carritoId;
   carritoUl.appendChild(liCarrito);
```

De esta forma, cuando quieras acceder al HTML del producto solo necesitas `document.getElementByID('producto-' + carritoId);` y te servirá para modificar o eliminar.

Finalmente, creo que vas a tener error al eliminar un producto del carrito, porque el método [.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop) siempre va a eliminar el último elemento, no importa si haces clic en la X del primero, segundo, etc.